# JPA + Hibernate = No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm trying to setup JPA for my Maven project, using Hibernate as provider.

**Structure of the project**

```
├── META-INF
│    └── persistence.xml
├── src
|   ├── main
|   |   └── java
|   |       ├── model
|   |       |   └── Instance.java
|   |       └── App.java
|   └── test
|       └── java
|           └── model
|               └── AppTest.java
└── pom.xml
```

**Content of persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="testjpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>it.vitrociset.model.Instance</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/aquasystem"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Content of Instance.java**

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Instance {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String path;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

}
```

**Content of App.java**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();
        userTransaction.begin();
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        instance.setId("id");
        instance.setPath("path");
        em.persist(instance);
        userTransaction.commit();
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**Content of pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testjpa
```

but I have no idea why. What is wrong in my code? I wasn't able to find the solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Persistence.xml is not in resources directory and therefore not in classpath. Move META-INF directory to src/main/resources.

Comment: I think you mean src/main/resources

Comment: My META-INF is in src/main/webapps. If I move it to `resources`, it tells me `Unable to locate persistence units`. It seems that this is progress.

Answer (score 5):

Add hibernate-entitymanager.jar to the classpath to resolve this issue.

Comment: This solved my problem when I tried to back-port to Java 1.7.
This is deprecated now, and hibernate-core is to be used instead.
However, without this hibernate was unable to find my Persistence Provider .... ????

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with hibernate 5. Switching to 4.3.11.Final fix it. The org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence wasn't in classpath.

Comment: in persistence.xml try using org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider as provider with Hibernate 5 instead of org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistene which you are using with Hibernate 4